# Presto - get sum of array elements

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I'm using Athena and trying to get a sum of array elements which are double but the reduce function seems to only work on integers:

`SELECT reduce(ARRAY [5.0, 20.0, 50.4], 0, (s, x) -> s + x, s -> s);`

Will throw an error:

`Unexpected parameters (array(double), integer, com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.TypeSignatureProvider@762f0fa7, com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.TypeSignatureProvider@29dfe267) for function reduce. Expected: reduce(array(T), S, function(S,T,S), function(S,R)) T, S, R`

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look clean but I have found a way to make it work:

```
SELECT reduce(ARRAY [5.0, 20.0, 50.4],
              CAST(ROW(0.0, 0) AS ROW(sum DOUBLE, count INTEGER)),
              (s, x) -> CAST(ROW(x + s.sum, s.count + 1) AS ROW(sum DOUBLE, count INTEGER)),
              s -> IF(s.count = 0, NULL, s.sum));
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a know bug in Presto. You can track https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/2760.

As a workaround, you can cast your `array(decimal(..))` to either `array(decimal(38,..))` or `array(double)`:

```
presto> SELECT reduce(cast(ARRAY[5.0, 20.0, 50.4] as array(decimal(38,5))), 0, (s, x) -> s + x, s -> s);
  _col0
----------
 75.40000

presto> SELECT reduce(cast(ARRAY[5.0, 20.0, 50.4] as array(double)), 0, (s, x) -> s + x, s -> s);
 _col0
-------
  75.4
```

Athena is based on an older Presto version (currently .172, 3 years old), and apparently none of the above works in Athena (based on the fact your array is already `array(double)`).

Comment: Thank you for your help, as you mentioned, the code doesn't work on Athena but it is good to know that it's a bug.